# Rendering problem on search page when using advanced search options

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

If I search for posts using almost any of the [advanced super ninja search options](https://stackoverflow.com/search), they don't seem to get rendered properly (`title` and `body` are the only ones that don't seem to cause a problem)

For example, searching for "[When are temporaries created as part of a function call destroyed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=When+are+temporaries+created+as+part+of+a+function+call+destroyed)" gives:

[image: Screenshot of the ok query]

Adding "[user:309308](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=When+are+temporaries+created+as+part+of+a+function+call+destroyed+user:309308)" turns it into:

[image: Screenshot of the problematic query]

Comment: Also, why is it inserting ellipses *into* words?

Comment: @Shog9 It's trying to show all the parts of the body that matched my search query, so it shows fragments with parts of my query highlighted, and doesn't care if those fragments end mid-word

Comment: right, but... It's not actually removing anything between some of the fragments. In your example, the start of the first fragment is actually *the start of the question*, with the next split happening in the middle of the word "stay" (with nothing actually removed between fragments). The same thing happens twice more (virtual...ly, c...ould) in the first example, and thrice more in the second (p...rintf, retu...rn, and char**...argv). Probably unrelated to your bug, but your thing makes it more obvious.

Comment: @Shog9 Oh, I didn't notice that; nice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed there was a regex issue with searches having *only* options and no *other* terms that wasn't being stripped down in some cases.  This has been fixed for the next build, it'll go out tonight.