# …Too… many… …elli…pses… … when searching… …

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, information-display, question-lists

The bug reported as [Rendering problem on search page when using advanced search options](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78546/rendering-problem-on-search-page-when-using-advanced-search-options) shows as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)—but there are still some issues. While it's no longer showing the raw HTML, it's now inserting far too many unnecessary ellipses (as seen here):

---

[image: search page filled with ellipses]

---

I understand using ellipses if only part of the text is being shown, but in these two examples, nothing's been removed. The ellipses are inserted at the beginning, at the end (twice!), and occasionally into the middle of words ("ins … urance", "passwo … rd", "patt … erns").

The search in question:

```
    https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=hasaccepted:0&tab=newest
```

<sub>[Insert profuse apologies here for the lack of handrawn circles!]</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was happening in the case of no-terms due to some display changes I made revamping search.  This will be corrected in the next build, the new behavior is:

- With terms: Except with ellipses, your search terms highlighted
- Without terms: A normal post summary, as you'd see elsewhere on the site (any other question list for example).

Comment: Is this already live? When terms are highlighted, [consecutive excerpts should probably not have ellipses between them](https://skitch.com/janfabry/rx6wx/questions-containing-unlock-iphone-backup).

Comment: @Jan - nope, the build will go out tonight :)